# How can I optimize this function which handles large c++ vectors?

Tags: c++, optimization, fft

According to Visual Studio's performance analyzer, the following function is consuming what seems to me to be an abnormally large amount of processor power, seeing as all it does is add between 1 and 3 numbers from several vectors and store the result in one of those vectors.

```
//Relevant class members:
//vector<double> cache (~80,000);
//int inputSize;

//Notes:
//RealFFT::real is a typedef for POD double.
//RealFFT::RealSet is a wrapper class for a c-style array of RealFFT::real. 
//This is because of the FFT library I'm using (FFTW).
//It's bracket operator is overloaded to return a const reference to the appropriate array element

vector<RealFFT::real> Convolver::store(vector<RealFFT::RealSet>& data)
{
    int cr = inputSize; //'cache' read position
    int cw = 0; //'cache' write position
    int di = 0; //index within 'data' vector (ex. data[di])
    int bi = 0; //index within 'data' element (ex. data[di][bi])

    int blockSize = irBlockSize();
    int dataSize = data.size();
    int cacheSize = cache.size();

    //Basically, this takes the existing values in 'cache', sums them with the
    //values in 'data' at the appropriate positions, and stores them back in
    //the cache at a new position.
    while (cw < cacheSize)
    {
        int n = 0;

        if (di < dataSize)
            n = data[di][bi];

        if (di > 0 && bi < inputSize)
            n += data[di - 1][blockSize + bi];

        if (++bi == blockSize)
        {
            di++;
            bi = 0;
        }

        if (cr < cacheSize)
            n += cache[cr++];

        cache[cw++] = n;
    }
    //Take the first 'inputSize' number of values and return them to a new vector.
    return Common::vecTake<RealFFT::real>(inputSize, cache, 0);
}
```

Granted, the vectors in question have sizes of around 80,000 items, but by comparison, a function which multiplies similar vectors of complex numbers (complex multiplication requires 4 real multiplications and 2 additions each) consumes about 1/3 the processor power.

Perhaps it has something to with the fact it has to jump around within the vectors rather then just accessing them linearly? I really have no idea though. Any thoughts on how this could be optimized?

Edit: I should mention I also tried writing the function to access each vector linearly, but this requires more total iterations and actually the performance was worse that way.

Comment: So is this a real bottleneck, after all? Or did you just look at it and concluded that "it consumes too much CPU"?

Comment: yeah, its for a real-time audio application, and the performance issue is audible

Comment: You do know stuff can be passed as reference

Comment: @Ed Heal sorry that was a mistake, it is passed by reference. Edited.

Comment: Do you have your compiler's optimization settings turned on and up?

Comment: @John Zwinck no, I didn't know there were optimization settings. I'll look into that, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn on compiler optimization as appropriate.  A guide for MSVC is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1ack8f1.aspx

Comment: Yes! Should have thought to look for that, the whole program runs 10x faster now.